# Update multiple fields of member of an instance simultaneously

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have a User model and this model

```
   class modelEmployer(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    employer_image      = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='')
```

Now suppose i have an instance of modelEmployer and I would like to update the content of the user object in it. I know I can do this

```
instance.user.email = new value
instance.first_name = new value
instance.save()
```

I read we can run an update on a queryset (even if it returns one object). Now suppose I have a dictionary like this

```
dict = {"first_name : "John","last_name" : "deer",....}
```

How can i do something like this
modelEmployer.object.filter(instance.user.email=dict["email"]).update(only update the user objects as I would like to update the user object of this field using directly the dictionary. Any suggestions ?

Comment: that is wrong. as this will return the modelEmployer query set and updating that through dict would be wrong as the dictionry contains only the key-values of the user object

Answer (score 1):

You can use explicitly mention the relation and do it,

```
dict = {"user__first_name" : "John","user__last_name" : "deer",....}
```

And in the ORM, do as

```
modelEmployer.object.filter(instance.user.email=dict["email"]).update(**dict)
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: yes i know i can do that but what if my dictiionary does not have `user__` appended to the start of its fields

Comment: If your `dict` is dynamically constructed, as you already know that you are having the field of `user` table in the dict you can blindly prepend `user__` to the keys of the `dict`

Comment: yes that would be my last action but I was just curious if there was a better way

Comment: I think you last statement is incorrect. It needs to be `.filter(user__email = ...)`

Comment: Also I dont think you can update foregin key values.u can only reference fields local to the model being updated.Please correct me if I am wrong